# How to get the last day of the prior quarter?

Tags: sql, date, datetime, sybase

How can I get the last day of the prior quarter?

```
Select DateAdd(day, -1, dateadd(qq, DateDiff(qq, 0, @Date), 0))
```

I found this SQL-Script, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The Script doesn't work in Sybase, because it can't compute the '0' you need the [Unix-Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unixtime).

for example:

```
DECLARE @LastDay datetime
SELECT @LastDay = DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, '01.01.1970', GETDATE()), '01.01.1970'))
SELECT @LastDay
```

Today (11/07/2013) This will Output:

```
30.09.2013 00:00:00
```

the Date-format can change, depending on how your Server ist configured.

If you don't want the Time, you have to change the datatype of `@LastDay` to `date`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function to utilize it in my project

```
CREATE FUNCTION preQtr
(@pQtr DATE)
RETURNS Date
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @OUTPUT DATE

SET @OUTPUT = (select DATEADD(D, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0,@pQtr), 0)))
RETURN @OUTPUT
END

select dbo.preQtr('2016-06-30')
select dbo.preQtr('2016-03-31')
```

Also, you can get datetime when you use like this: [image]

```
select DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0,'2016-03-31'), 0)) As PreviousQuarterLastdayTime
select DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0,'2016-03-31'), +1)) As QuarterFirstdayTime
```